Whats that animated movie?
I apologize in advance, I don't recall much about the movie. I remember it was an animated film probably from the mid to late 80s.  
All I can remember is the ending credits played a song that literally consisted of the syllable "LA" over and over again, in a repetitive melody then changed to "DA" etc... If I recall at the end of the movie a girl walks into the ocean and is lifted up by something as she walks along. Either a series of sea creatures or maybe rocks rising out of the water. 
Again, I was very young so the memory is foggy. If this sounds familiar to anyone, let me know!

So Literally after submitting this I kept googling, which I swear Ive been doing on and off for years and found it. Its called Nausicaä of the valley of the wind

it's ok to answer your own question. Just make sure to add enough substance to your answer.

Smurfs? laah laaah la lah lah lah, laah la lah lah lah....

If I am not wrong, it is Nausicaa of the Valley of the Wind, it has the same song described:




You might want to elaborate in which way this fits to the descriptions from the question in order to flesh out the answer a little more.
